# Conversion of a premium-adjusted delta to a strike

Tags: fx, delta

I am trying to compute the calibration of an FX market volatility surface, and especially I want to retrieve the strikes from the deltas quoted.

I don't have any trouble reverse-engineering the formulas for non premium-adjusted deltas. However, for many currency pairs, the convention is to use premium-adjusted deltas, which are not monotonic in strike. For example, for a premium-adjusted forward delta (Source: [Clark - FX Option Pricing - Chap3 p47](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470683686)):
$$
\Delta_{F;\%} = \omega\frac{K}{F_{0,T}}N(\omega d_{2})
$$

Following [this source, p14](http://www.frankfurt-school.de/clicnetclm/fileDownload.do?goid=000000425413AB4):

> One common solution to this problem is to search for strikes corresponding to
>   deltas which are on the right hand side of the delta maximum.

What is the argument or the intuition behind this statement?

Comment: I guess the intuition behind this is that the market tends to quote out-of-the-money options. For calls, these are on the upside and thus right of the max. delta strike.